# Can I prove there are more than 1 fixed points of an affine map?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

If I have a map of the form $Mr+c $ where $M$ is a real matrix, $r$ is a point, and $c$ is a constant vector, how could I show that this transformation has more than 1 fixed point for a specific case where is does? I looked into the Lefschetz fixed point theorem but couldn't tell if I can use that or how.

Comment: What do you mean? Unless you give a specific $M$, how could one prove this?

Comment: the situation you talk about happens if and only if $\operatorname{rk}(M-I_n)<n$ and $\operatorname{rk}(M-I_n\mid c)=\operatorname{rk}(M-I_n)$. Lefschetz fixed point theorem (along with all the theorems which talk about *compact* spaces) does not seem appropriate, since $\Bbb R^n$ is not compact.

Comment: I have $M$ and $c$, but they have rather big entries of 3 diffrent variables. I could write them out in full but i was wondering if there is a way of testing it for the general case.

Comment: In my case it is a map from the unit ball to the unit ball if that helps.